# Combinatorics - N families, each family consists of {dad, mom, child, dog} sitting on a circular table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

N families, each family consists of {dad, mom, child, dog} sitting on a circular table.

there are (4n-1)! ways to sit them

in how many the parents always sit together and the dogs never together?

What i tried to think of is calculating, all possibilities ( (4n-1)! ) - possibilities of dogs sitting together

but calculating the possibilies of all the dogs sitting together is kinda impossible, because assuming n=5 then 5 dogs and i have to find number of ways for 5 dogs sitting together then 4 dogs sitting together , and 3, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Your original estimate of $(4n-1)!$ provides a good starting point for the analysis

The issue of the parents always sitting together is easily dealt with by presuming that each pair of parents is **glued together** into one unit.  This means that instead of $(4n)$ units, you have only $(3n)$ units.

However, you have to adjust that within each internal parent-unit, there are (2!) ways of internally permuting the components of the parent-unit.

Therefore, absent the issue re the dogs, the (*new starting*) computation is

$$[(3n-1)!] \times [(2!)^n].$$

Fortunately, positioning the dogs also admits elegance.  Remembering that each pair of parents is an inseparable unit, you actually have (not counting the dogs), a **dogless** computation of

$$T_1 ~=~[(2n-1)!] \times [(2!)^n].$$

There are exactly $(2n)$ *slots* between these $(2n)$ units.  The $n$ dogs must be assigned into these slots, with no more than 1 dog assigned to any one slot.  This can be done in the following number of ways:

$$T_2 = \binom{2n}{n} \times n!.$$

Therefore, the final answer is

$$T_1 \times T_2.$$

---

**Addendum** 
Responding to the comment/question of Light Lamps.

Explanation best given with a **thought-experiment**.  Suppose that :

- You have a round table with $4n$ chairs.
- Each child sits in one chair.
- Each set of two parents sit together in **only one chair**.  That is, each parent-unit is **sharing** only one chair, with one parent using the left-half of the chair, and one parent using the right-half of the chair.
- The $2n$ chairs now occupied are each separated by exactly 1 empty chair.
- This means that you have $2n$ empty chairs **alternating** with $2n$ occupied chairs.

**In this thought experiment**, suppose that you focus on where one specific child is seated at the circular table.  Since the occupied chairs [i.e. the $2n$ chairs assigned to humans] alternate with the empty chairs, the position of the occupied chairs is **fixed** (in relation to the specific child being focused on).

With respect to that child, the $(2n-1)$ other units [$(n-1)$ children and $n$ parent-units] may be permuted in $(2n-1)!$ ways, among the $2n$ chairs assigned to humans.

Note that for each parent-unit, there are $(2!)$ ways that the parent-unit may be **sharing** a chair, with one parent on the left and one parent on the right.  This explains my computation of

$$T_1 ~=~[(2n-1)!] \times [(2!)^n].$$

Now, the constraint that each set of parents **sit together** has been satisfied.  The dogs are going to be assigned seats from the $2n$ remaining (unoccupied) chairs.  This satisfies the constraint that no two dogs sit next to each other.

- There are $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways of selecting which of the $2n$ currently unoccupied chairs will be used by the dogs.
- Having selected the $n$ chairs to be used by the dogs, there are $(n!)$ ways of permuting the dogs in the $n$ chairs assigned to them.

This explains my computation of

$$T_2 = \binom{2n}{n} \times n!.$$

This means that the computation of

$$T_1 \times T_2$$

is appropriate for the **thought experiment**.

What about the actual seating of the $4n$ (people + dogs) around the table, where

- $4n$ chairs are used
- No chairs are left unoccupied.
- The parents sit together.
- No two dogs sit next to each other.

There is a **bijection** between the thought experiment and the actual seating.  That is, each thought experiment seating corresponds to exactly 1 actual seating:

- In the actual seating, with one parent in a chair to the left of the other parent, it corresponds to the thought experiment where both parents share a chair, with one parent using the left side of the chair.
- In the actual seating, where a child does **not** have a dog on his immediate left (for example), this corresponds to the thought experiment where the child has an empty chair to his left.
- In the actual seating, where the set of parents do **not** have a dog on their immediate left, this corresponds to the thought experiment where the parents have an empty chair on their left.

Because of the **bijection** between the thought experiment and the actual seating, the computation of $T_1 \times T_2$ is **also** appropriate for the actual seating.

Comment: Why there are 2n slots left for the dogs? its supposed to be n, since 2n units stand for 3 people, the parents and the son

Comment: @LightLamps See the Addendum to my answer, which I have just added.